# File Object not present in request payload, present as empty array

Tags: node.js, angular, file, express

this one is absolutely stumping me.  I have a large form inserting into a database, and among the formControls is a input="file" that I end up saving along with the rest of the form information to an interface with all of it's corresponding data members.  Everything does so fine and gets sent in the insert POST request except for the following.

Data member in Interface class (Javascript object and base64encodedstring)

```
releaseNotesFiles?: Array<[File, any]>
```

Relevant code for processing on submit.

```
  if (this.changeForm.get('changeOverviewFG.releaseNotesRadio').value === 1) {
    const file = this.changeForm.get('changeOverviewFG.releaseNotesFiles').value[0];
    const url = this.rnBlobs[0];
    this.change.releaseNotesFiles.push([file, url]);

  }
```

The file itself as the base64 encoded string gets moved properly to the interface data member, the File itself does not.  However upon debugging, it appears to do both properly.  Screenshots included...

[image]

[image]

So I'm a bit stumped when it comes to actually submitting it to the node.js backend and it shows this in the request payload...

[image]

I haven't a clue why this behaviour is happening.  If someone could help me find a lead I would be eternally grateful.

Edit: Including express/body-parser information as per request

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
router.use(express.json({limit: "50mb"}));
router.use(express.urlencoded({limit: "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit:50000}));
```

Comment: Are you using a body parser?

Comment: Yes the one built into express 4.1.6 and later.  Edited post to include that info.

Comment: What is the content type of the request?

Comment: Multipart/form-data?  I just left work so my capacity to confirm is limited until tomorrow!

Comment: Ok, that's it then, your body parser won't handle `multipart/form-data`. Try implementing https://github.com/pillarjs/multiparty or https://github.com/mscdex/busboy

Comment: I will take a look at that!  Thank you so much.